# Strip text with jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

How can I remove the `<p>` and `</p>` tags from the text in the span with class "strip"? *(The `<p>` is included into the some atom feed I'm grabbing.)*

The `<p>` tag is posted as normal text so on the front-end I see `<p>Here some text</p>`

I'd like to use JS to remove `<p>` and `</p>` in the text with class "strip"

`<span class="strip"><p>Here some text</p></span>`

This isn't working:

`$( ".strip p" ).unwrap;`

**EDIT --- See here:**

[image]

Comment: `$(".strip").text() ` would be "Here some text" - i.e. text content only.

Comment: what does "isn't working" mean? Do you get an error? Try `$( ".strip p" ).unwrap();` But I don't think it does what you think it does. https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/ . It will remove the "strip" element and leave you with the "p" element. But it will still be an element object with the tags, not just the text.

Comment: `jQuery.unwrap` is a function, you have to use `()` to call it: `$( ".strip p" ).unwrap();`.

Comment: Ah sorry, in the source I now see its `&lt;p&gt;`.
See my example fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6n32agbw/1/

Comment: How did they get there in the first place?

Comment: Sorry I'm not really clear. I grab a feed where its already into. So I can't edit that.

Comment: See here: accountantsportal.nl/feed/cfd5d6373e636f49f9ea61e38aedd2de/atom

Comment: Right. you grab said feed, how does it end up in your page? If you're inserting html using the text mothod... that's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

If you want just text use text() function instead of html().
Like,

```
$(".strip").text()
```

If you want something else, please clarify. I will update the answer.

Solution as per your need and more optimized approach using regEx and unwrap function:
https://jsfiddle.net/6n32agbw/8/

```
var elem = $(".strip").text();
var decodedtext = getDecodeValue(elem);

var finalValue = getInnerString(decodedtext);
alert(finalValue);


function getDecodeValue(text){
return $(".strip").unwrap().text();
}


function getInnerString(val){
return val.replace(/(<\/?\w+>)/g,"");
}
```

Comment: I have added an image of the website in the main post. Its showing <p>
Because its a feed I can't edit it. Just want to remove <p> and </p> text out of the span with class="strip". A function is like: `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: Hi Nitesh, it is still showing the <p> in your example.

Comment: Did you check the new solution?
Why it has been downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvoted it. Sorry it took so long to reply. I'm not sure what the solution was but I think some CMS parameter is used like :striptags. Its to difficult to look it up again.. Nested somewhere deep..